# Going to a company page invalidates prior search

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

When searching for a job and then looking at a company page going back to your initial search page invalidates your search.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to stackoverflow.com/jobs
2. Search javascript in the **Keywords** search
   [image]
3. Click any result such as **trivago's** listing for a **JavaScript Software Engineer** (where you can find a hotel for less).
4. Click on the company page of **trivago**.
   [image]
5. Go back to **search jobs**
6. Your search for javascript is cleared

[image]

It would be nice to maintain this when looking for a position because you may in fact want to read up on the company and then continue searching.

PS: Trivago if you are reading this thanks for saving me hundreds on my hotel stays.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Is the declined because the "<< search results" button effectively does this and that going back to the "search jobs" tab is indeed meant to clear the previous search?

Comment: @JonClements effectively yes, see my reply below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the feature request. However, in this case we won't be implementing this.

The reason is that we would need to preserve the search query across visits to `http://stackoverflow.com/jobs`, which doesn't make sense within the current UI. Clicking on that tab is synonymous with starting a new search.

In addition, you can continue search by simply using the browser's back button.

Comment: Is "<< search results" also synonymous with using the browser's back button?

Comment: @JonClements correct, it effectively sends you back to the same page.

Comment: Okay although I don't agree with how this works.  It's quite confusing.